# How to auto-scale based off of GPU Utilization in GCP managed instance groups

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine, autoscaling

I want to auto scale our instances based off of GPU utilization per instance in a time series. What is the utilization target supposed to be?

[image: Adding a auto scaling metric to google cloud managed instance group]

I found this page that documents the type (Gauge INT64 %) [Metrics GPU Utilization](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#:%7E:text=of%20this%20pipeline.-,job/gpu_utilization,-BETA%0AGPU%20utilization) and tried 50 but I keep getting this error/flag

[image: error when setting auto scaling metric to google cloud managed instance group gpu utilization]

Comment: Is there any particular error message shown aside from the red warning sign?

Comment: To provide an accurate answer to your issue, please share the error message shown by the platform.